# Way to write code "in the debugger" in Lua?

Tags: lua, koneki

I just played around a bit with Lua and tried the Koneki eclipse plugin, which is quite nice. Problem is that when I make changes in a function I'm debugging at the moment the changes do not become effective when saving the changes. So I'm forced to restart the application. Would be so nice if I could make changes in the debugger and they would become effective on the fly as for example with Smalltalk or to some extend as in hot code replacement in Java. Anybody has a clue whether this is possible?

Answer (score 5):

It is possible to some degree with some limitations. I've been developing an [IDE/debugger](http://studio.zerobrane.com) that provides this functionality. It gives you access to a remote console to execute commands in the context/environment of your running application. The IDE also supports [live coding](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10937422/1442917), which reloads modified code as you make changes to it; see demos [here](http://studio.zerobrane.com/tutorials.html).

The main limitation is that you can't modify a currently running function (at least without changes to Lua VM). This means that the effect of your changes to the currently running function will only be seen after you exit and re-enter that function. It works well for environments that call the same function repeatedly (for example a game engine calling `draw`), but may not work in your case.

Another challenge is dealing with upvalues (values that are created outside of your function and are referenced inside it). There are methods to "read" current upvalues and re-create them when the (new) function is created, but it requires some code analysis to find what functions will be recreated to query them for upvalues, to get the current values, and then to create a new environment with those upvalue and assign proper values to them. My current implementation doesn't do this, which means you need to use global variables as a workaround.

There was also [relevant discussion](http://lua-users.org/lists/lua-l/2013-04/msg00641.html) just the other day on the Lua mailing list.

Comment: Insightful answer, Paul. Thanks.

Comment: I think the reason this works in Smalltalk is because the whole code is a binary snapshot (in Smalltalk called the "image") which is entirely in memory (Smalltalk link libraries came much later when Kava was already there). So I guess Smalltalk seems to be the only language where you can do this. Quite a pity ...